# Crypt java to js and decrypt

Tags: android, node.js, encryption, kotlin

Does someone knows how to encrypt in java and decrypt in nodejs ?
No matter the algorithm, aes/cbc would be better but it doesn't matter.

After days and days passing in searching a solution it seems that the algorithm is not the same in the two languages.

Here is my code in kotlin/java:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val text = "Hello everybody !"
    val password = "1234567812345678"

    val encrypted = encrypt(text, password)
    Log.i("MainActivity", "encrypted = $encrypted")
    val decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, password)
    Log.i("MainActivity", "decrypted = $decrypted")
}

private fun encrypt(text: String, password: String): String
{
    val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(password.toByteArray(), "AES")
    val ivSpec = IvParameterSpec(password.toByteArray())
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec)

    val results = cipher.doFinal(text.toByteArray())

    return Base64.encodeToString(results, Base64.NO_WRAP or Base64.DEFAULT)
}

private fun decrypt(text: String, password: String): String
{
    val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(password.toByteArray(), "AES")
    val ivSpec = IvParameterSpec(password.toByteArray())
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec)

    return String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT)))
}
```

and here is my code in nodejs:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');


var text = "Hello everybody !"
var password = new Buffer("1234567812345678")
console.log("Password = " + password)


var encrypted = encrypt(text, password)
console.log("Encrypted = " + encrypted)

var decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, password)
console.log("Decrypted = " + decrypted)

function encrypt(data, password)
{
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', password, password);
    var crypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex');
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return crypted;
}

function decrypt(data, password)
{
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', password, password);
    var dec = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf8');
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return dec;
}
```

I already read all the tutorials about that but nothing is working.

Comment: You're returning base64 from Kotlin and trying to decode hex in NodeJS...  How would that ever work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intent to use your code with strings like this, your code is almost completely correct. You just use incorrect encoding in `node.js` part.

Change encrypt and decrypt of `node.js` to `base64` as following:

```
function encrypt(data, password)
{
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', password, password);
    var crypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64');
    crypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return crypted;
}

function decrypt(data, password)
{
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', password, password);
    var dec = decipher.update(data, 'base64', 'utf8');
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return dec;
}
```

and change `base64` encoding in java part to following:

```
private fun encrypt(text: String, password: String): String
{
    ...
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(results)
}

private fun decrypt(text: String, password: String): String
{
    ...
    return String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(text)))
}
```

Now result of encrypt/decrypt of `Java` an `node.js` matches up. :)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didn't look around the encoding, but now I will be carefull about that.